# Check free disk space using Batch commands

Tags: windows, batch

Is there a way already to check the free space of a hard drive in a batch script?

I'd rather not use third party apps since I need to fill out a lot of forms, and in that case I think I'll write a small app myself.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to reliably get at the free disk space is using WMI. When trying to parse the output of `dir` you get all kinds of funny problems, at the very least with versions of Windows in other languages. You can use `wmic` to query the free space on a drive:

```
wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace
```

This will output something like

```
FreeSpace
197890965504
```

You can force this into a single line by adding the `/format:value` switch:

```
> wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value

FreeSpace=197890965504
```

There are a few empty lines there, though (around three or four) which don't lend themselves well for processing. Luckily the `for` command can remove them for us when we do tokenizing:

```
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%x
```

The nice thing here is that since we're only using the second token all empty lines (that don't have a second token) get ignored.

Remember to double the `%` signs when using this in a batch file:

```
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x
```

You can now use the free space which is stored in the environment variable `%FreeSpace%`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script to check your c-drive

```
echo C-drive Free Space >> CDrive.txt
dir c:\|find /i "bytes free" >> CDrive.txt
```